# An application of Fermat little theorem

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Suppose $p>3$ is a prime number. Why $7^p-6^p-1$ is divisible by $43$?

I know $(7\times6)^p\equiv -1 \pmod{43}$; but I don't know how use this fact to show the above assertion. Any idea will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

We find $7^6\equiv1\pmod{43}$ and $6^6\equiv1\pmod{43}$. Each prime $p>3$
has the form $6k+1$ or $6k+5$. So $7^p-6^p-1=7^{6k+1}-6^{6k+1}-1\equiv7^1-6^1-1\pmod{43}$ or $7^p-6^p-1=7^{6k+5}-6^{6k+5}-1\equiv7^5-6^5-1\pmod{43}$
leaving two cases to check.

Comment: Equivalently,in the field $\mathbb Z_{43}$ we have $7^{6k+5}-6^{6k+5}-1=$ $7^{6k+6}7^{-1}-6^{6k+6}6^{-1}-1=$ $7^{-1}-6^{-1}-1=$ $ (-6)-(-7)-1=0.$...................................+1.